# Including Images in Pop-Up Display of KML-imported Data Points in Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

The Google team recommended I take one of my support questions here. Here it is:

"I've imported a set of data points from a kml file into Google Earth. The import worked fine--the points are all in the right locations and they display the proper data when they're clicked. The only problem is that when a point is clicked, its pop-up balloon does not display the images that are supposed to be associated with the point. Instead, the "pictures" field just displays a tiny question-mark icon. I'm curious if there's any way to display a point's actual associated images in the pop-up balloon when the point is clicked. I know I could manually upload each image to each data point, but I'm looking for a way to automatically include the images when the kml is imported. All of the pictures that the points reference are located as .jpg files in the same folder that the kml file is located in."

Any thoughts?

Comment: Create a [KMZ file](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives) which includes the pictures and the KML [KMZ tutorial for google earth](http://www.google.com/earth/outreach/tutorials/kmz.html)

Comment: this worked, the images are now showing in the pop-up box when their icon is clicked. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> ...the "pictures" field just displays a tiny question-mark icon

It sounds as if the path is simply incorrect. To fix this use absolute URLs to the images from within the KML rather than relative ones. i.e.

rather than  `<img src="yourimage.jpg" />` 
use `<img src="http://yourserver.com/yourimage.jpg" />`

If that isn't the issue then could you post an example of your KML?

Comment: geocodezip's suggestion did the trick, but thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Create a [KMZ file](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives) which includes the pictures and the KML [KMZ tutorial for google earth](http://www.google.com/earth/outreach/tutorials/kmz.html)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to insert many kind of object is use CDATA element and write all of your information as HTML element
For more information visit
[KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#description)